# Why doesn't malloc allocate memory at all?

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc, heap-memory

I have the following struct:

```
struct block {
    void *addr; /*start address of memory for this block */
    int size;
    struct block *next;
};
```

I have the following code to initialize each block:

```
void block_init(struct block *b, void *addr, int size){

    /*Allocate space and fill b with the initial data.*/
    b = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    if(b){
        b->addr = addr;
        b->size = size;
        b->next = NULL; 
    }    
}
```

I am calling the following lines from another function:

```
struct block *list;
block_init(freelist, mem, size);
```

However, it never  initializes the block.

I used gdb to test this, however everytime I get a NULL pointer:

```
123     b = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block);
(gdb) next
124     if(b){
(gdb) print b
$2 = (struct block *) 0x0
(gdb) print b->size
Cannot access memory at address 0x8
```

I don't know what's going on, can someone help me out?

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: I have a hunch you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>` in your .c file.

Comment: You only modify the local variable `b`. You either need your parameter `b` to be a pointer to pointer called with `&list` (so it can change the contents) or (probably easier) return the malloced block.

Comment: Also, you need to read: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: @John3136: The phrase "double pointers" is ambiguous. You mean pointers to pointers, not `double*`.

Comment: @DMan, What you are doing is a *Pass by Value*, In that case, you could collect the return value back to `freelist`, or Use *Pass by reference*, by passing the address of the pointer (Using double pointer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `block *`, so if you change value of b, it will not reflect to calling function. You should use `block**`.

```
void block_init(struct block **b /*HERE*/, void *addr, int size){

    /*Allocate space and fill b with the initial data.*/
    *b /*AND HERE*/ = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    if(*b){
        (*b)->addr = addr;
        (*b)->size = size;
        (*b)->next = NULL; 
    }    
}
```

Call Function,

```
block_init(&list , mem, size);//pass by address
```

Comment: How does an answer that clearly doesn't compile get accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Without disagreeing with what @pranit-kothari said, a possibly more idiomatic way of writing the original function is

```
struct block* block_init(void *addr, int size) {
    /*Allocate space and fill b with the initial data.*/
    struct block* b = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
    if (b) {
        b->addr = addr;
        b->size = size;
        b->next = NULL; 
    }
    return b;
}
```

That avoids modifying any arguments (which I usually feel is a 'code smell'), is rather clearer to read, and is probably tidier to call.

(Just by the way, was the `malloc` argument supposed to be `size * sizeof(struct block)`?)